# How to get approximate x,y coordinates of an object on a webpage?

Tags: html, vba, layout, coordinates, extract

I'm new to this website as well as vba and html (started learning/using both a month ish ago) so please be forgiving with my quality of question. The code I've put below is what I've written to upload values from an excel file onto a website. The part I'm struggling with is the line ***SetCursorPos x, y***. So to explain why I have that there in the first place: I needed to click a button "Add" at the bottom of a user form that was initially summoned by clicking another button "Add Client". For some reason, **.Click** wasn't working here. So to solve this problem, I found code online for simulating a mouse click. That worked but I needed to place the cursor on the "Add" button myself. I did find that I could use a SetCursorPos function to place the cursor where I needed but I'm not sure how to get the x,y coordinates of the button in the first place. I've tried parsing through the source code but I can't find all the location information I need for the button object. If I click "layout" when I've selected the html code that corresponds to the Add button, I see the information I'm looking for, but I don't know how to extract this either. I'm not getting anywhere from my online searches. Any suggestions or ideas??

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub JoistUpload()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String

Dim NumberOfModulesToRun As Integer
NumberOfModulesToRun = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("B12").Value

Dim ModulesToRun()     'Dynamic Array
ReDim ModulesToRun(NumberOfModulesToRun - 1)
j = 0
For i = 2 To 10
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Cells(i, 2).Value = 1 Then
    ModulesToRun(j) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Cells(i, 1).Value
    j = j + 1
End If
Next i


Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://my.joistapp.com/dashboard/estimate/new"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    .Document.GetElementsByClassName("ember-view document-header-client waves-effect waves-green btn-flat")(0).Click


    .Document.getElementbyID("name").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O2").Text
    .Document.getElementbyID("email").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O3").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("phoneMobile").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O4").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("phoneOther").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O5").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("address1").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O7").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("address2").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O8").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("city").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O9").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("state").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O10").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("zip").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O11").Text, True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    .Document.getElementbyID("ember1872").Select
    Application.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("O12").Text, True


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    'SetCursorPos x, y
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

    For i = 0 To NumberOfModulesToRun - 1

        FilePath = "C:\Users\Bloom\Documents\Renovation Express\Quote Code\" & ModulesToRun(i) & "Module.txt"
        TextFile = FreeFile
        Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
        FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("ember-view waves-effect waves-green new-document-item btn-green btn-flat waves-effect waves-light button-with-image")(0).Click
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("ember-view btn-green btn waves-effect waves-light")(2).Click
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("unstyled materialize-textarea ember-view ember-text-area")(i).Value = FileContent
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("no-padding unstyled is-valid ember-view ember-text-field")(i).Value = ModulesToRun(i)
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("no-padding unstyled ember-view ember-text-field")(3 * (i) + 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall").Range("A:A").Find(What:=ModulesToRun(i)).Offset(0, 3).Value
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("document-tax-col placeholder")(0).Click
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("toggle-bar")(3).Click
        .Document.GetElementsByClassName("ember-view btn-green btn waves-effect waves-light")(3).Click
        Close TextFile

        Next i

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Bloom\Documents\Renovation Express\Quote Code\NoteForClient.txt"
    TextFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
    .Document.GetElementsByClassName("materialize-textarea ember-view ember-text-area")(NumberOfModulesToRun).Value = FileContent
    Close TextFile

    .Document.getElementbyID("issued-date").Click
    .Document.GetElementsByClassName("btn-flat picker__today")(0).Click


End With

End Sub
```

Some of the source code related to the form where the Add button is:

```
</p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></section><div 
class="modaler"><div class="modal modal-view" style="top: 70.3px; width: 
700px; height: 562.4px; display: block; min-height: 0px; max-width: 700px;" 
data-is-push="false"><div class="ember-view modal-wrapper" id="ember1841">
<div class="modal-header"><div class="title"><!----><span>New Client</span>
</div><div class="actions"><a class="ember-view btn-green btn waves-effect 
waves-light" id="ember1842"><!----><span>My Clients</span><!----></a></div>
</div><div class="modal-content"><p><div class="ember-view" id="ember1851">
<div class="ember-view col-header form-header" id="ember1860"><h3 
class="col-header-title">Basic Information</h3></div><div class="ember-view 
fixed-label input-field is-valid" id="ember1861"><div class="joist-input-
container-wrapper"><input class="  is-valid   ember-view ember-text-field" 
id="name" type="text"><label class="false active" for="name">Name</label><!-
---></div><!----></div><div class="ember-view fixed-label input-field is-
valid" id="ember1862"><div class="joist-input-container-wrapper"><input 
class="  is-valid   ember-view ember-text-field" id="email" type="text">
<label class="false" for="email">Email Address</label><!----></div><!---->
</div><div class="ember-view fixed-label input-field is-valid" 
id="ember1863"><div class="joist-input-container-wrapper"><input class="  
is-valid   ember-view ember-text-field" id="phoneMobile" type="text"><label 
class="false" for="phoneMobile">Phone (mobile)</label><!----></div><!---->
</div><div class="ember-view fixed-label input-field is-valid" 
id="ember1864"><div class="joist-input-container-wrapper"><input class="  
is-valid   ember-view ember-text-field" id="phoneOther" type="text"><label 
class="false" for="phoneOther">Phone (other)</label><!----></div><!---->
</div><div class="ember-view col-header form-header" id="ember1865"><h3 
class="col-header-title">Additional Information</h3></div><div class="ember-
view fixed-label input-field is-valid" id="ember1866"><div class="joist-
input-container-wrapper"><input class="  is-valid   ember-view ember-text-
field" id="address1" type="text"><label class="false" 
for="address1">Address</label><!----></div><!----></div><div class="ember-
view fixed-label input-field is-valid" id="ember1867"><div class="joist-
input-container-wrapper"><input class="  is-valid   ember-view ember-text-
field" id="address2" type="text"><label class="false" for="address2">Address 
2</label><!----></div><!----></div><div class="ember-view fixed-label input-
field is-valid" id="ember1868"><div class="joist-input-container-wrapper">
<input class="  is-valid   ember-view ember-text-field" id="city" 
type="text"><label class="false" for="city">City</label><!----></div><!---->
</div><div class="ember-view fixed-label input-field is-valid" 
id="ember1869"><div class="joist-input-container-wrapper"><input class="  
is-valid   ember-view ember-text-field" id="state" type="text"><label 
class="false" for="state">State</label><!----></div><!----></div><div 
class="ember-view fixed-label input-field is-valid" id="ember1870"><div 
class="joist-input-container-wrapper"><input class="  is-valid   ember-view 
ember-text-field" id="zip" type="text"><label class="false" for="zip">Zip / 
Postal Code</label><!----></div><!----></div><div class="ember-view input-    
field input-field-textarea fixed-label input-field is-valid" id="ember1871">
<div class="joist-input-container-wrapper"><textarea class="materialize-    
textarea  ember-view ember-text-area" id="ember1872" style="height: 23px;">
<!----><br></textarea><label class="false">Private Notes</label></div></div>
</div></p></div><div class="modal-action"><!----><a class="ember-view btn-
grey btn waves-effect waves-light" id="ember1873"><!----><span>Cancel</span>
<!----></a><a class="ember-view btn-green btn waves-effect waves-light" 
id="ember1874"><!----><span>Add</span><!----></a></div></div></div></div>
<div class="modal fade alert-view"><!----></div><div class="ember-view 
select-view" id="ember679"><!----></div><div class="loading-overlay" 
style="display: none;" data-ember-action="680"></div></div><div 
class="material-tooltip"><span>Estimates</span><div class="backdrop" 
style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="material-tooltip">
<span>Invoices</span><div class="backdrop" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
</div></div><div class="material-tooltip"><span>Clients</span><div 
class="backdrop" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div 
class="material-tooltip"><span>Items</span><div class="backdrop" 
style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="material-tooltip">
<span>Settings</span><div class="backdrop" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
```

Comment: Why are you using send keys, and not setting the value of the HTML element instead.  You can use `.click` or `.firevenet("click")` off it  as you've done `.Document.GetElementsByClassName("toggle-bar")(3).Click`

Comment: What is your error on .click, or does nothing happen?

Comment: I've used SendKeys instead of .Click because the website would not "save" these values if I used .Click in these places. So when I click the Add button after values have been inputted using .Click, nothing gets uploaded. I found this strange too but I had the same problem when I was using .Click to input the email and password for this website in an earlier code. I thought maybe the website needed me to simulate human/manual entry to prove I wasn't a robot

Comment: I did not get the problem of my input not getting uploaded/saved if I used .Click instead of SendKeys everywhere, which is why I've used SendKeys in only some places @Nathan_Sav

Comment: can you post some of the html it may be something like `forms(0).submit` that you need, if the button calls the forms submit event

Comment: I just tried forms(n).submit with various values of n but it did not work. I got the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: The events that I see when I inspect the Add button are mouseleave and mouseup @Nathan_Sav

Comment: I've added some of the source code. Lines 12 and 13 (counted from the end) have the Add button, for reference

Comment: Did you prefix the form with `.document`

Comment: Hmm I had not before. But trying it as .Document.Forms(0).Submit is giving me another error: "This error (HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but the site has a programming error." @Nathan_Sav

Comment: Maybe because there are two buttons at the bottom? Cancel and Add

Comment: rather than clicking the element, try something like `element.form.submit`  I cant really see much without the web site, so cant be much more help.  The error 405 can be from the wrong submission method, so you could do some research around that.